# ¿Cómo crear notificación si la hora la da el usuario?

Tags: android, push-notification

El usuario registra su hora mediante el siguiente código en un `EditText`

```
if (v == btnTimePicker) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Launch Time Picker Dialog
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {

                        txtTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                        String s=txtTime.getText().toString();
                        Ob.insertar_hora(s);


                    }
                }, mHour, mMinute, false);
        timePickerDialog.show();
    }
```

Mi duda es como hacer para que la hora registrada en el `EditText` se vuelva notificación.
¿Y también para que esa notificación se repita cada 3 horas?

Aún no entiendo como hacerlo, si me pudieran ayudar a entender como colocarlo, soy nuevo en android y no entiendo muchas cosas. Gracias. 
Mi codigo completo (si sirve de algo), quiero que con los datos seleccionados en el TimePicker se active una notificacion a la hora seleccionada.

```
public class paciente extends AppCompatActivity {
private static String TAG;
EditText med;
private int horas;
private int minutos;
private TimePicker timePicker1;
private Button botonEjemplo;
private AlarmManager alarmaManager;
private PendingIntent alarmaIntent;
Button btnDatePicker, btnTimePicker;
EditText txtTime, medicamento, dosis, proxima_toa, hora;
private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_paciente);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    medicamento = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    dosis = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    hora = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);


    btnTimePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button21);
    txtTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}


public void algo(View v) {


    if (v == btnTimePicker) {

        // Get Current Time
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Launch Time Picker Dialog
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {

                        txtTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);

                    }
                }, mHour, mMinute, false);
        timePickerDialog.show();

    }


}


public void aceptar(View view) {
    ConexionBD C1 = new ConexionBD(this);
    C1.abrirConexion_Medicamentos();
    String m, d, t, h;
    m = this.medicamento.getText().toString();
    d = this.dosis.getText().toString();
    t = this.txtTime.getText().toString();
    h = this.hora.getText().toString();
    C1.agregar_med(m, d, t, h);


}
```

}

Comment: Oscar, revisa la respuesta de Joacer, creo que responde a tu pregunta, para obtener el texto del EditText simplemente es  editText.getText().toString(); , saludos!

Comment: txtTime toma la hora (hora:minutos), que valor toma hora?, esto donde agregas los valores a la base de datos

Answer (score 3):

Para que la hora registrada se vuelva notificación creo que bastaría con crear la notificación pasandole la fecha recogida por tu `EditText`

```
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
      final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
      c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
      c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

      creaNotificacion(c.getTimeInMillis(), "Titulo de la notificacion", "Contenido de la notificacion", context);
}
```

Por otro lado para repetir algo cada X tiempo puedes utilizar el AlarmManager:

- [Documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)
- [Ejemplo](http://www.carlos-garcia.es/tutorial/android-alarmas-alarmmanager)

y para las notificaciones `NotificationCompat`

- [Documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html)

A continuación te dejaré un código de cómo lo haría aproximadamente

**Código para crear una alarma cada 10 minutos**

```
public static void setAlarm(Context context) {
        AlarmManager mgr =(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        //configuramos una alarma para que se haga el envio de las notificaciones sino esta creada ya
        boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

        if (!alarmUp){
            Log.i(TAG, "create an alarm");

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);  
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  

            mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+60000,
                    PERIOD,
                    pIntent );
        }else{
            Log.i(TAG, "Alarm is already active");
        }
}
```

**Código para el receiver de la alarma, que es donde podrás lanzar la notificación**

```
public class MyReceiver extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver {  

    @Override  
    public void onReceive(android.content.Context context, android.content.Intent intent) {  
         //Tu lógica de negocio irá aquí. En caso de requerir más de unos milisegundos, deberías usar un servicio
         creaNotificacion(System.currentTimeMillis(), "Titulo de la notificacion", "Contenido de la notificacion", context);
    }  
}
```

En el manifest deberás declarar el receiver del siguiente modo:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver "></receiver>
```

**Código para generar las notificaciones:**

```
public static void creaNotificacion(long when, String title, String content, Context context) {
    try {
        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.logoapp);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Activity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setWhen(when)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(content)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logoapp)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);

        notificationManager.notify((int) when, notificationBuilder.build());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "crearNotificaciones:" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: La pregunta es demasiado amplia pero acabo de ver tu respuesta y es demasiado amplia y excelente.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Elenasys

Comment: pero no encuentro como acoplarlo a mi código, me marca errores, me podrías ayudar ?

Comment: @oscarramirez dime que problemas tienes e intentaré ayudarte lo mejor que pueda

Comment: En que parte de mi código se debe de colocar para la notificación?  Y también el context de creanotificacion(c. Timeinmillis ()...  Me marca error

Comment: `c.getTimeInMillis()` la variable c no se refiere al contexto sino a la varialble `final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();`, en cuanto al bloque de crearNotificacion lo puedes poner en la misma `Activity` o crearte una clase java por ejemplo Utilidades.java y poner la función dentro

Comment: el error que me aparece es en el context de        creaNotificacion(c.getTimeInMillis(), "Titulo de la notificacion", "Contenido de la notificacion", **context**); (es el que esta en negrita), me dice que no lo encuentra,nigun context y ya coloque todos las partes del codigo

Comment: @oscarramirez el context es el contexto de la Activity, puedes declararte una variable llamada context en tu Activity e inicializarla en tu OnCreate() de la siguiente forma, `context = this;`. Espero que esto te ayude a quitar el error

Comment: @oscarramirez conseguiste solucionarlo?